# No instance of overloaded function "CVector4::operator" matches the specified type / term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

Tags: c++, class, matrix, operator-overloading, implementation

I'm attempting to implement both a Vector4 class, and a Matrix4x4 class in C++ to get a better handle on the language. I've looked around, and nothing seems to have really answered the problems I've encountered, though apologies if I've missed anything.

Edit: The original error no longer seems to be occurring (It was caused by circular inclusion). However, now I'm receiving the following error:

```
1>main.cpp(35): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
```

I could only imagine this occurring because of my overloading of the () operator in CMatrix4x4, however it did not occur in my previous code when called from main().

Requested SSCCE case:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

class CMatrix4x4;

class CVector4
{
public:
    float x, y, z, w;

    CVector4();
    CVector4(float, float, float, float);
    ~CVector4();

    CVector4    operator*(CMatrix4x4&);
};

CVector4::CVector4()
{
    x, y, z, w = 0;
}
CVector4::CVector4(float cx, float cy, float cz, float cw)
{
    x = cx, y = cy, z = cz, w = cw;
}

//No instance of overloaded function "CVector4::operator" matches the specified type
//<error-type> m
//DOES NOT occur with forward declaration of class, only when including matrix.h
//from a separate file.
//Now causes "term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments" at lines: 35-38
//Whenever I call the overloaded operator ()
CVector4 CVector4::operator*(CMatrix4x4& m)
{
    CVector4 v;
    v.x = x*m(0, 0) + y*m(1, 0) + z*m(2, 0) + w*m(3, 0);
    v.y = x*m(0, 1) + y*m(1, 1) + z*m(2, 1) + w*m(3, 1);
    v.z = x*m(0, 2) + y*m(1, 2) + z*m(2, 2) + w*m(3, 2);
    v.w = x*m(0, 3) + y*m(1, 3) + z*m(2, 3) + w*m(3, 3);
    return v;
}

class CMatrix4x4
{
public:
    CMatrix4x4();
    ~CMatrix4x4();

    void SetRow(int r, CVector4);

    float operator()(int r, int c);

    private:
    float   matrix4x4[4][4];
};

CMatrix4x4::CMatrix4x4()
{
    for(int r = 0; r < 4; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
        {
            matrix4x4[r][c] = 0;
        }
    }
}

CMatrix4x4::~CMatrix4x4()
{
}

float CMatrix4x4::operator()(int r, int c)
{
    assert(r >= 0 && r < 4);
    assert(c >= 0 && c < 4);
    return matrix4x4[r][c];
}

void CMatrix4x4::SetRow(int r, CVector4 v)
{
    assert(r >= 0 && r < 4);
    matrix4x4[r][0] = v.x;
    matrix4x4[r][1] = v.y;
    matrix4x4[r][2] = v.z;
    matrix4x4[r][3] = v.w;
}

int main()
{
    CMatrix4x4 m;
    CVector4 vec1(1, 2, 3, 4);
    CVector4 vec2;

    m.SetRow(0, CVector4(1, 0, 0, 0));
    m.SetRow(1, CVector4(0, 1, 0, 0));
    m.SetRow(2, CVector4(0, 0, 1, 0));
    m.SetRow(3, CVector4(0, 0, 0, 1));
    vec2 = vec1 * m;
    std::cout << vec2.x;
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Thank you to all who assisted. I managed to resolve this by moving function implementations to separate .cpp files (Which I should have done to begin with. I have no clue why I didn't), and including the required headers there, and using forward declaration in the header files.

I'm not sure if this is the correct solution, however it does appear to be functional.

Comment: FYI, member functions that don't (and shouldn't) modify member variables, should be declared `const`.  `operator *` is a good example.

Comment: The code you show contains _undefined behaviour_. In the `operator*` function you return a reference to a local variable. After the function returns this reference now "points" to unused memory. Using it will cause strange behaviour to happen, or even crashes.

Comment: The code looks superficially ok, syntactically (see also http://ideone.com/DQlgA3).  Please construct an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) test-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem as in many questions asked before: the original version of your code apparently has two header files - `vector.h` and `matrix.h` - which include each other. This is circular inclusion, which does not achieve anything meaningful.

The include guards you probably have in your header files make sure that the inclusion does not become infinite. But they do nothing to resolve the circular dependency between your data types. The `CMatrix4x4` is completely unknown in your `vector.h`, which leads to an error.

Forward declaration of `CMatrix4x4` in `vector.h` is a step in proper direction. However, you have to get rid of that useless circular inclusion anyway. And you have to keep in mind that `CMatrix4x4` will be an incomplete type in `vector.h`, meaning that you will not be able to access its internals in `vector.h`.

The latter means that your `CVector4 CVector4::operator*(CMatrix4x4& m)` has to be defined *after* the definition of `CMatrix4x4`, not before. In your code it is defined before `CMatrix4x4`. At that point type `CMatrix4x4` is still incomplete, meaning that your cannot use its `()` operator. Expressions like `m(0, 0)` will not compile for that reason specifically. That's the reason for the error you are getting.

P.S. Additionally,

```
x, y, z, w = 0;
```

doesn't do what you probably think it does. It will assign `0` to `w`, but leave other data members unchanged (read about comma operator in C++).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It cleared up quite a bit for me, although I'm still somewhat confused as to what I should do to resolve the issue considering that they are in separate files, and forward declaration will/does leave them as an incomplete type. Would removing the dependance upon the matrix be a good solution, or is there something else that I should do instead?